# jQuery plugin to wrap text around images + support IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-6, excanvas

This is a tall order, but is there a jQuery or Mootools (or other framework) plugin to wrap text around images and support IE6? I've tried the jQSlickWrap, but unless the browser supports HTML 5, you're out of luck. What's strange is that IE 6 supports the jQuery Background Canvas plugin, which uses the CANVAS object (via excanvas.js) just as this plugin does. Thanks.

Edit: Here's the relevant code; this code works in Firefox and Safari but not on any version of IE; it just places the text to the left of the image but not over it:
    
      .testimonialImage {
        float:right;
      }

```
 <script src="global/js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
 <!--[if IE]>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="global/js/excanvas/excanvas.js" ></script>
 <![endif]-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="global/js/slickwrap/jquery.slickwrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.testimonialImage').slickWrap();
});
 </script>

 <img src="global/img/testimonial.gif" width="434" height="315" class="testimonialImage" />
 <p>I grew up watching Public TV. Now, Tina and I watch the great programming together. <br />
  &mdash; Jennifer T.</p>
```

Comment: Can you link to an example of this? It sounds like something really simple easily achievable with CSS unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi, Infinity. Take a look at this on Firefox: http://jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/example3.html

Comment: You might just have to revert back to adding your own divs. It's a little bit more painful, but not hard. Check out this tutorial (http://www.bigbaer.com/css_tutorials/css.image.text.wrap.htm)

Comment: Thanks, fudgey. I think your solution is the only one that works for now, until IE starts to behave like the other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the main reason it's not working is lack of canvas support in IE6 (an HTML5 element used to draw shapes with javascript).

Google wrote [this great script](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) that enables support for the canvas element in IE. In fact, they use it in Google Maps and some of their other applications.

You can include that only for IE using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). That should make jQSlickWrap work.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, yuval. I'm using the excanvas.js script for the jQuery Background Canvas plugin and that works fine on IE 6 (though not for IE 5.5 or below). However, it's not working for IE 6 or 7, but works for Firefox and Safari; I'm doing something wrong. I've posted the relevant code to my original post above.

Comment: I believe I know why the jQSlickWrap isn't working on any version of IE -- IE doesn't support the toDataURL() function, so even the excanvas.js library won't help. The developer of the jQSlickWrap said this on his site: http://jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/