# wrap text around image IE

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer

I have done a bit of searching for a solution to wrap text around an image and came across the JQSlickWrap.
[jQuery plugin to wrap text around images + support IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457266/jquery-plugin-to-wrap-text-around-images-support-ie6)

But it is not working in IE. Is there another way to wrap text around an image? Or is that just not possible for IE yet?...

Great wrap example in firefox but not so great in IE:
http://jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/example1.html

There is this manuel way to create div's but in my case that is a no-go since it is multible images uploaded by a webmaster.

Br. Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible.  It's using the canvas element, which isn't supported.  There are [drop-in](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/flash-canvas/) [solutions](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) that mimic a canvas tag using VML, but VML [doesn't support](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=67&can=1&q=getImageData) the getImageData method, so those solutions can't read the image data to find the wrapping points.

Comment: ok, thanks. Just had to check ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question full but I think if you just add an align attribute to an image i makes the other content in the parent container to wrap around the image from the other direction of the align value.

```
<img src="bla" align="right"/>
```

then the text would wrap around it from the left.

Comment: No that is not it. Try this link IN BOTH IE AND FIREFOX then you will see what is meant: http://jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/example1.html